# Sql COUNT column by date and select the correspondent date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I read berfore [SQL Count for a Date Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375781/sql-count-for-a-date-column) and [SQL to get count by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388590/sql-to-get-count-by-date) but these does not point my problem.

I have the following table records (the table has only two columns)

```
| VALUE   | TIME               |
--------------------------------
| test    | 04.05.2012 11:46:46|
| test2   | 04.05.2012 11:46:49|
| test3   | 06.05.2012 11:47:46|
| test2   | 05.05.2012 11:47:46|
| test    | 04.05.2012 11:51:46|
```

I want to display like:

```
| VALUE   | COUNT   | NEWTIME  |
--------------------------------
| test    | 2       |04.05.2012|
| test2   | 1       |04.05.2012|
| test2   | 1       |05.05.2012|
| test3   | 1       |06.05.2012|
```

I counted `VALUE` by using `day` as datepart of `TIME` like:

```
select datepart(d, TIME), count(VALUE) from table1
group by datepart(d, TIME)
```

How to get also the additional `NEWTIME` column ? It is possible in SQL Server 2005 ?

Thank you

Comment: I do not entirely understand the meaning of `newtime`, but you could try adding `max(datepart(d, DATE))` after `count(...)`.

Comment: `datepart(d, TIME)` returns the **day of the month**. Is that really what you want? It will group `2012-05-07` with `2012-06-07`.

Comment: Yeah, you've right...Maybe I have to group by day+month+year is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select VALUE,
       count(*) as COUNT,
       dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, TIME), 0) as NEWTIME
from YourTable
group by VALUE, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, TIME), 0)
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69311)

Comment: how to group by year+month+day ?

Comment: Can show me please how to leave hours, minutes and seconds intact ? because if I use `dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, TIME), 0)` then the time is 00:00:00. I want to leave them intact

Comment: @MichaelSwan - You can't have the time part in the result and at the same time group on date only.

Comment: Then per hour if is possible or per minutes

Comment: @MichaelSwan You can have the time part for **one** of the rows that makes up a group. Like `min(TIME)` or `max(TIME)`. If you think about it you see that if a group on day is composed of many rows with different time parts you have to choose what time you want on the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it and format it like so, but you will have to also group by it.

```
select value, datepart(d, TIME), count(VALUE), datepart(mmonth, time) + '.' + datepart(day, time) + '.' + datepart(year, time) as newtime
from table1
group by datepart(d, TIME, newtime)
```

If you don't care about using the period as your seperator, then it can be done a bit easier.

```
select value, datepart(d, TIME), count(VALUE), convert(varchar, time, 101) as newtime
from table1
group by datepart(d, TIME, newtime)
```

I also noticed that you have duplicates in your output, personally, I would do this instead:

```
select value, count(*) as cnt, convert(varchar, time, 101) as newtime
from table1
group by value, newtime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select VALUE, count(VALUE), datepart(d, MIN(TIME)) AS NEWTIME
from table1
group by datepart(d, TIME)
```

You can use either `MIN` or `MAX` aggregate function. In your case it shouldn't matter as you're grouping at a *whole day* level via `datepart`.

Answer (score 0):

havent tested, but i would do it like that

```
select VALUE, count(*) AS COUNT, convert(date, max(TIME)) AS NEWTIME --max , min whatever 
from table1
group by VALUE, datepart(d, TIME) --dont know why you group by timne not value
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get your question but if I understand it correcty you would like to group the data by short date from the time column? If so the result is:

```
select max(VALUE) as VALUE, count(VALUE) as count, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TIME , 104) as newtime
from table1
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TIME , 104)
```

I dont get why to display the values if you don't group by them